# Cumulative sum based on respective last values of subgroup

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame:

```
DF <- data.frame(Observation = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17),
                 ID          = c('A','A','B','C','D','D','B','B','B','B','A','A','A','B','D','D','C'),
                 Group       = c('X1','X2','X1','X1','X2','X2','X2','X1','X1','X2','X2','X2','X2','X1','X2','X1','X1'),
                 Value       = c(1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1))
```

I would like to take the cumulative sum by 'ID' (not complicated) but only based on the respective last values of the 'Group' each ID is part of. In other words: For each 'ID', create the cumulative sum for all last available values of those 'Group's where the ID is present (can include the current value within a given row given the reference on the last available value).

Detailed Explanation: Example for ID = A:

In (`1`) `ID` = `A` refers to `X1` in (`1`) with value = `1`, leads to a cum_sum = `1`.

In (`2`) `ID` = `A` refers to `X1` in (`1`) with value = `1` and `X2` in (`2`) with value = `0`, leads to a cum_sum = `1`.

In (`11`) `ID` = `A` refers to `X1` in (`1`) with value = `1` and `X2` in (`11`) with value = `1`, leads to a cum_sum = `2`.

In (`12`) `ID` = `A` refers to `X1` in (`1`) with value = `1` and `X2` in (`12`) with value = `1`, leads to a cum_sum = `2`.

In (`13`) `ID` = `A` refers to `X1` in (`1`) with value = `1` and `X2` in (`13`) with value = `0`, leads to a cum_sum = `1`.

The final result looks like this.

```
DF_Result <- data.frame(Observation = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17),
                        ID          = c('A','A','B','C','D','D','B','B','B','B','A','A','A','B','D','D','C'),
                        Group       = c('X1','X2','X1','X1','X2','X2','X2','X1','X1','X2','X2','X2','X2','X1','X2','X1','X1'),
                        Value       = c(1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1),
                        Cum_Sum     = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,2,2,1,1,0,1,1))
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Yes, packages and basic functions are already known - but it's not simply the cumulative sum based on one ID - it's the cumulative sum by ID for each last value of the group (Group) the ID is part of or assigned to

Comment: @Dan Your second row for 'A', logic you said is `ID = A refers to X1 in (1)` is it like checking the previous value.  It is not that clear

Comment: I did not get the logic of your "refers to". Your desired result is not `ave(DF$Value, DF$ID, DF$Group, FUN=cumsum)` or `ave(DF$Value, DF$ID, FUN=cumsum)`

Comment: @jogo: You're right - this is not the result (this is the simple cumulative sum by two groups).

Comment: @akrun: You're right - you can call it the previous value (which is the last occurrence of that value)

Comment: @Dan Here is the one I don't understand when you say cumsum, for e.g. the 13th row changed from 2 to 1.  are you subtracting 1 when there is a 0

Comment: @akrun: In (13) ID = A refers to the two available previous values: X1 in (1) with value = 1 and X2 in (13) with value = 0. The  cumulative sum equals 1 (0+1). For clarification: I mentioned 'last' value to make clear that the value refers to the last available value (which can be the value of the current row).

Comment: Will `Group` always be `X1` or `X2`? Or there could be many other Groups as well?

Comment: @Ronak Shah Thanks. There can be (many) other groups (it's a simplified example).

Comment: I think the logic is not clear when I look into different "ID"s

Comment: @akrun. We checked the logic several times. Let me know if you have questions...

Comment: e.g. For ID = "B", value changed from 2 to 1 (row 8 to 9) - both are X1 and the value is 1 and 0.  Did you subtract it.  Similarly 9 to 10, it is 0, while the previous X2 value is 2

Comment: @akrun: Here is the detailed example for ID = B: In (3) ID = B refers to X1 in (3) with value = 1, leads to a cum_sum = 1.
In (7) ID = B refers to X1 in (3) with value = 1 and X2 in (7) with value = 1, leads to a cum_sum = 2.
In (8) ID = B refers to X1 in (8) with value = 1 and X2 in (7) with value = 1, leads to a cum_sum = 2.
In (9) ID = B refers to X1 in (9) with value = 0 and X2 in (7) with value = 1, leads to a cum_sum = 1.
In (10) ID = B refers to X1 in (9) with value = 0 and X2 in (10) with value = 0, leads to a cum_sum = 0.
...

Comment: @Dan Based on the logic, I was checking the 'ID' 'D", In (5), Value = 0, CumSum = 0,-> fine, In (6), Value = 1, Cumsum = 1, then comes 15, Value = 0, Cumsum -> 0 (0 + 1 = 1) ?

Comment: Here is the detailed example for ID = D: In (5) ID = D refers to X2 in (5) with value = 0, leads to a cum_sum = 0. In (6) ID = D refers to X2 in (6) with value = 1, leads to a cum_sum = 0. In (15) ID = D refers to X2 in (15) with value = 0, leads to a cum_sum = 0. In (16) ID = D refers to X1 in (16) with value = 1 and X2 in (15) with value = 0, leads to a cum_sum = 1.

Comment: @Dan There is a typo in your last comment `In (6) ID = D refers to X2 in (6) with value = 1, leads to a cum_sum = 0`  Should it be 1.  I get the what the rows you are referring to, but you are saying that it `leads to a cum_sum = 0`, How?

Comment: @Dan e.g. how it leads to a cumsum of 0 from 6 to 15 for 'D'

Comment: Let's check here `setDT(DF_Result)[, grp := rleid(Group), ID][, v1 := last(Value), .(ID, grp)][ID == "D"]`  You said `last` 'Value', so I am taking last value.  Not clear how the values are changing (if you check the subset data with `setDT`

Comment: @akrun. You're right. The correct version: In (6) ID = D refers to X2 in (6) with value = 1, leads to a cum_sum = 1. Please apologize the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed with some others that the explanations are a bit hard to understand... But here is my attempt: do you mean that you are trying to compute the per-ID sum of the per-ID and per-group cumulative last value?

If so, here is an implementation. The trick is to compute the per-ID and per-group derivative (like `diff()`) and them take its `cumsum()` per ID:

```
DF %>% 
  group_by(ID, Group) %>% 
  mutate(Diff = Value - lag(Value, default=0)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Cum_Sum = cumsum(Diff))
```

Comment: Thanks, Pierre. This seems to work perfectly (also for N > 2 groups). I'm currently testing several modifications (by now, it works as anticipated). Great!

Comment: Great. Let us know if you need some modifs

Comment: Yes, works with additional subgroups and also with alterations of the default. I assume that cumsum can be replaced by any further operation (such as mean), right? Anyhow, great!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the sentiments expressed in the comments that this is not clear. To be honest (and I really don't mean this as an offense), this is an awful problem description, with ambiguous/non-standard terms ("refer to") and confusing explanations.

Perhaps the following is a step towards finding a solution; it does not reproduce your expected output completely, but is getting close. Here's hoping you actually made a mistake in your expected output, because quite frankly I can't work out the logic.

```
DF %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(
        n = 1:n(),
        Cum_Sum = if_else(n > 1, Value + first(Value), Value)) %>%
    select(-n)
## A tibble: 17 x 5
## Groups:   ID [4]
#   Observation ID    Group Value Cum_Sum
#         <dbl> <fct> <fct> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1           1 A     X1        1       1
# 2           2 A     X2        0       1
# 3           3 B     X1        1       1
# 4           4 C     X1        0       0
# 5           5 D     X2        0       0
# 6           6 D     X2        1       1
# 7           7 B     X2        1       2
# 8           8 B     X1        1       2
# 9           9 B     X1        0       1
#10          10 B     X2        0       1
#11          11 A     X2        1       2
#12          12 A     X2        1       2
#13          13 A     X2        0       1
#14          14 B     X1        1       2
#15          15 D     X2        0       0
#16          16 D     X1        1       1
#17          17 C     X1        1       1
```

I translated your problem statement into this: `Cum_Sum` is the sum of the current `Value` and the *first* value in that `Group`; if the current value is the first value, `Cum_Sum` is simply the current `Value`.

The first 9 rows are identical to your expected output; I have no idea why `Cum_Sum` for row 10 is 0...

---

### Update

Hopefully edging closer to what you're trying to do

```
DF %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(Cum_Sum = Value + lag(Value, default = 0))
## A tibble: 17 x 5
## Groups:   ID [4]
#   Observation ID    Group Value Cum_Sum
#         <dbl> <fct> <fct> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1           1 A     X1        1       1
# 2           2 A     X2        0       1
# 3           3 B     X1        1       1
# 4           4 C     X1        0       0
# 5           5 D     X2        0       0
# 6           6 D     X2        1       1
# 7           7 B     X2        1       2
# 8           8 B     X1        1       2
# 9           9 B     X1        0       1
#10          10 B     X2        0       0
#11          11 A     X2        1       1
#12          12 A     X2        1       2
#13          13 A     X2        0       1
#14          14 B     X1        1       1
#15          15 D     X2        0       1
#16          16 D     X1        1       1
#17          17 C     X1        1       1
```

Provided I understood your "logic" correctly this has really nothing to do with a cumulative sum; instead this is simply

[image]

per `ID`.

If you'd like to do this per `ID` and per `Group`, simply replace `group_by(ID)` with `group_by(ID, Group)`.

Comment: Value at position 10 is 0 instead of 1 (based on `DF_Result`

Comment: @akrun Yes, sadly:-) I have no idea why though (see the last sentence of my post)... here's hoping OP made a mistake or perhaps this will help clarify the problem.

Comment: Also, for the 14, I have doubts which I raised in the comments

Comment: Thanks. Please read the examples I posted below the original posts: In (10) ID = B refers to X1 in (9) with value = 0 and X2 in (10) with value = 0, leads to a cum_sum = 0. In (14) ID = B refers to X1 in (14) with value = 1 and X2 in (10) with value = 0, leads to a cum_sum = 1. (Always the last available value for respective subgroups).

Comment: @Dan What do you meant by the last available value?

Comment: @Mauritus Evers: Despite the fact that your approach does not include a reference on the group (Group) it is restricted to only two groups, right? (I mentioned that this is an example but the approach should be applicable to many potential groups).

Comment: @Akrun: Mhhh...not sure how to understand your question, but last available value should be clear (at least based on the example). In other words: For each ID, create the cumulative sum for all last available values of those Groups where the ID is present.

Comment: Sorry, @akrun. Can we keep serious?

Comment: @Dan Yeah, sure, but your comments are somewhat lacking the specific logic that we need to understand.  Think about it.  4-5 people have attempted this (and many others without acknowledging).  So, would it be nice to frame the logic a bit differntly

Comment: @akrun Thanks. I tried to provide a further explanation in the original post.

Comment: @Dan *" Despite the fact that your approach does not include a reference on the group (Group)"* Your examples do not suggest that `Group` plays *any* role. Either your example is not representative or we are (once again) misunderstanding each other. Also concerning *"Please read the examples I posted below the original posts"* you can rest assured that everybody who has spent time trying to help with your issue has *thoroughly* read your post. The confusion arises from exactly those examples you give. This has been pointed out to you *multiple* times now, to no avail.

Comment: @Maritus Evers: "Your examples do not suggest that Group plays any role". First, Group is included in the example data. Second, 'Group' is mentioned in the text data as relevant. Third, 'Group' is included in the result data. Fourth, Group is included in most of the comments. Do you make fun? Seriously, Maurits? The logic is clear (we checked it with five people). But again, seriously, majority vote for logic?

Comment: And again. There is a consistent logic in the result column (Cum_Sum) that is not expected to be comprehensible without further explanation (that is, however, provided) but existent.

Comment: @Dan Dan, I think you're misinterpreting your role in all this. *You* are asking for *our* help. Multiple people have pointed out in comments that your rules/logic are not clear. Your continued dismissal of our requests to clarify is not really clear to me. Reflect on what you're trying to achieve here, be polite and not condescending, otherwise you won't be having a good time around here. For what it's worth, I've updated my post to include my revised interpretation of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Mauritus Evers: Sorry, but despite thinking in 'roles' and 'you'/'we', I try (tried) to explain the challenge I have :) It's that simple, Maritus :)

Comment: okay guys, I have to go now.  WIll check on this post later :=) Woke up at 3:30 am and now it is around 9 am.

Comment: @Mauritus Evers Thanks. It reproduces the example, yes, but is not applicable to N > 2 Groups (in the example, I defined two groups (X1 and X2 for simplification). For my actual application (and probably more relevant for further references on this post) I have N > 2 Groups  (X1, X2, ... XN).

Comment: @Dan Hmm, that should be straight-foward to implement now that we've established that you are after the sum of the current and lagged vector. The easiest would be to suitably convert from wide to long, group by the resulting group key and then calculate `Cum_Sum` by group. Can you add a minimal data example with >2 groups (including expected output)? It's easier to show with sample data; something with three grouping columns `X1`, `X2` ,`X3` would be good.

Comment: Here is an example with three groups (X1, X2, and X3). `DF <- data.frame(Observation = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26),
                        ID          = c('A','A','B','C','D','D','B','B','B','B','A','A','A','B','D','D','C','A','A','A','A','A','B','D','D','C'),
                        Group       = c('X1','X2','X1','X1','X2','X2','X2','X1','X1','X2','X2','X2','X2','X1','X2','X1','X1','X1','X2','X3','X2','X3','X3','X3','X3','X3'),
                        Value       = c(1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0))`

Comment: And the result column: `Cum_Sum     = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,2,2,1,1,0,1,1,1,2,3,2,1,2,2,1,1)`

Comment: @Dan You're very welcome, glad you got there in the end. I see from Pierre's answer that the key was to the cumulative sum of the *difference* between successive values within `ID` and `Group` by `ID`.